# Can you take a fractional root of a number?

Tags: roots, exponentiation

Is it possible to say, take a 1,5th root of 2? And if not why so? Wouldn’t a 0,5th root of a to the third power = a to the power of 3/0,5 = a to the power of 6? If this is not allowed than why?

Comment: See [Rational exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents)

Answer (score 4):

Usually (when $x$ is a positive number) $\sqrt[n]{x}$ can be treated as $x^{1/n}$, and this extends to non-integral $n$. So $\sqrt[1.5]x$ can be interpreted as $x^{2/3}$, and if $a\ge0$ we do have $\sqrt[0.5]{a^3}=a^{3×2}=a^6$.

Comment: So this is valid? I’m asking this question since my maths teacher told me “you can never take a fractional root of a number”, which seemed very weird and unnecessarily restrictive

Comment: @OtoroshiBeats You can never _in general_ (over negative numbers, complex numbers, etc.) take a fractional root (or indeed _any_ root) of a number without breaking some laws of exponentiation.